# PHP - Globally Set A Trim Function

Tags: php, echo, global, trim

I am trying to trim a GET variable in a globally included file.

I'm trying to set the following code in my global include,

```
$profile = $_GET["profile"];
trim($profile, "/");
```

Then when I try to echo $profile, the only way to trim / out, is to manually trim it out in the file I echo it in.

Comment: `$profile = trim($_GET["profile"], "/");`?

Answer (score 2):

how about, returning the trimmed value back to a variable:

```
$profile = $_GET["profile"];
$profile = trim($profile, "/");
```

or

```
$_GET["profile"] = trim($_GET["profile"], "/");
$profile = $_GET["profile"];
```

Comment: Although both answers work, I like Martin's because its one line. I thank you though as I tested these and they do work. Thank you for the answer though, I know other methods now =]

Comment: sure, no problem. If I removed the second line, it basically the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to advocate modifying at the global level (generally *it is bad*) but..

```
$_GET["profile"] = trim($_GET["profile"], '/');
```

And it will be modified in the superglobal array.

It would be better to store your tmmed version in the session or similar.